# more short code about if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

i wanted to try the following code:

```
//all arrays are List<T> type.
if (m.terms[0] != null && m.terms[0].labels != null && m.terms[0].labels[0].title == "Part-of-speech")
{
    result = true; 
}
```

but it occured runtime error occasionly in following situation

> **i.** m.terms == null
>
> **ii.** m.terms != null, but m.terms[0] does not intialized.
>
> **iii.** m.terms != null, and m.terms[0] has been exist but
>   m.terms[0].label does not initialized.

...

so i did modify it to like this:

```
if (m.terms[0] != null)
{
    if (m.terms[0].labels != null)
    {
        if (m.terms[0].labels[0].title == "Part-of-speech") { result = true; }
    }
}
```

is it the best way?

Comment: Both of your examples do exactly the same thing, they're just formatted differently.  You'll need to perform more explicit checks on the values which can be null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` is a short circuiting operator, so the first way you wrote it and the second way will be functionally equivalent.

```
if (a && b && c)
{
    // work 
}
```

`b` will only be evaluated if `a` returns true. (Same goes for `c`).

In your code, checking `m.terms[0].labels` will not be a problem because you would have short-circuited out of the expression if `m.terms[0]` had been null.

To completely cover yourself, you'd want to possibly add checks for `m` and `m.terms`, however.

```
m != null && m.terms != null && m.terms.Count > 0 && m.terms[0] != null ...
```

As it evaluates from left to right, it will break on the first condition that doesn't pass and the rest will go unchecked.

Comment: oh. i modify it if (m.terms != null && m.terms[0].labels != null && m.terms[0].labels[0].title == "Part-of-speech") so it worked properly. thanks.

Comment: This answer is not complete nor is the OP's solution. If m.terms != null && m.terms.Count == 0, the code will fail. While it is checking for a null Collection, it doesn't check that a item exists in the collection.

Comment: @Andrew, good catch on the Count (or length) check, it should have been included.

Comment: I think this is better. Less code.
result = (m.terms[0] != null && m.terms[0].labels != null && m.terms[0].labels[0].title == "Part-of-speech");

Answer (score 3):

```
int index = 0;
int labelIndex = 0;
string titleToCheck = "Part-of-speech";

if (m != null && m.terms != null && m.terms.Count > index)// or m.Length...
{
    if (m.terms[index] != null && m.terms[index].labels != null &&
        m.terms[index].labels.Count > labelIndex)
    {
        if (m.terms[index].labels[labelIndex].title == titleToCheck)
        {
            result = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all about readability. C# uses [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) so in functionality there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (m!=null && m.terms!= null && m.terms[0].labels!=null && m.terms[0].labels[0].title!=null && m.terms[0].labels[0].title == "Part-of-speech")
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it would be better to split off each null check into a separate if statement.

The reason is that the second and third conditions require the first to not be null. If the first is null, then the second and third conditions will in turn throw errors because their parent is null yet is trying to be accessed.

Comment: Simply not true, && in C# is short-circuiting.

Comment: Ahh, so it is! Sorry, then yes it doesn't matter and is just readability :)